# How should I parse and understand the following sentence (“…, … of which …”)?

Tags: relative-pronouns

> From [MSDN - `IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221306(v=vs.85).aspx):
>
> #### `rgDispId`
>
> Caller-allocated array, each element of which contains an identifier (ID) corresponding to one of the names passed in the `rgszNames` array.

I've understood those `__ which` things as just inversion of prepositions.
For example, when I see this clause: “Trees **of which** a forest consists.”, I just move the `of` to the end of it: “Trees **which** a forest consists **of**.”

But in this case, it seems the method does not work properly. I cannot *understand* it: “Caller-allocated array, each element **which** contains an identifier (ID) corresponding to one of the names passed in the `rgszNames` array **of**.”

I interpreted the sentence as “A caller-allocated array **whose elements** contain an ID corresponding to one of the names passed in the `rgszNames` array”. I can *guess* what it means, but I want to understand the grammatical structure of the sentence, so as to know the reason why it brings the meaning.

I've read:

- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/322836/how-to-correctly-apply-in-which-of-which-at-which-to-which-etc

Comment: As a learner: "of which" is the formal form of "whose". I mean it's preferable to use "of which" rather than "whose" in formal writing.

Comment: Now I get the concept. I stopped moving the preposition to the end of the sentence to understand it. Instead I put the modified noun (`a caller-allocated array` herein) in place of the basic ones, such as `which`, `whom`, `what`, and et cetera, and think of the `each element of which` where the `which` is "the array" to be a single relative pronoun that connects the two things in-between. It makes perfect sense and would be the _right_ way to interpret those I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct. *Which* does indeed refer back to the *caller-allocated array*.

You are not wrong in replacing *of which* with *whose*, but especially in formal writing, there are people that like to stick to using *who* for people only (or at least, animate objects).

After all, *whose* is nothing else than a short version of *of whom*, completely similar to *of which*. But we don't have an equivalent "short version" of *of which* (which could be **which's* or something like that?).

So formally we use *who* for people, *which* for objects:

> The man *of whom* the car was stolen = The man *whose* car was stolen.
>   The car *of which* the tires were stolen = *The car *which's* tires were stolen.

Note that that last sentence is not correct, I just included it for illustration!

Comment: Oh, so `of which` here is basically `whose` for inanimate objects. Thank you so much. Besides it, is considering `(prep.) which` as inversion of prepositions so _putting the preposition into the end of the clause_ when interpreting it, wrong way to interpret `(prep.) which`? It worked for many sentences that have `(prep.) which`, but seems to be not working for some I mentioned.

Comment: @K._ It is not a _wrong_ way to interpret it, but you should be aware it is not a _universally applicable_ way to interpret it. Yes, in many cases prepositions can have several correct places in a sentence, but not always. Just remember that there is hardly _any_ so-called "rule" in any language that has _no_ exceptions :)